# VBA Loop with multiple ifs won't compile, not sure why

Tags: vba, excel, loops, excel-2010

I'm trying to get two columns of data on one sheet rearranged into rows on another sheet, controlled by a column on the first sheet.

I'm going through the code, debugging it with the F8 command, and have run into an issue with the looping command at the end. I'm getting a "Loop without Do" compile error, with the "Loop Until" at the end highlighted by Excel.

This is what it's supposed to do:

- The "JCX" (10, AttributeRowCounter) cell and "08-Attribute" (1, AttributeRowCounter) should match, and control which row in "JCX" the "08-Attribute" (11,AttributeRowCounter) value goes.
- The "08-Attribute" (9,AttributeRowCounter) value controls which column in "JCX" to put the "08-Attribute" (11,AttributeRowCounter) value.
- If there's a list of values in "08-Attribute" (1, AttributeRowCounter) called AHU-2, with corresponding list of values in "08-Attribute" (9, AttributeRowCounter) as "CFM, EAT, LAT, RPM, and SP", then the value in "08-Attribute" (11,AttributeRowCounter) with CFM in (9,AttributeRowCounter) goes in the "JCX" (14,TagNumberRow).
- The value in "08-Attribute" (11,AttributeRowCounter) with RPM in (9,AttributeRowCounter) goes in "JCX" (16,TagNumberRow).
- The value in "08-Attribute" (11,AttributeRowCounter) with SP in (9,AttributeRowCounter) goes in "JCX" (15,TagNumberRow).
- If there is a value in "08-Attribute" (11,AttributeRowCounter) that has something other than "CFM, SP, RPM, and Motor HP" in (9,AttributeRowCounter), then the value in (11,AttributeRowCounter) goes in "JCX" (21,TagNumberRow), and the value in (9,AttributeRowCounter) goes in "JCX" (20,TagNumberRow).
- The previous statement loops, to load any additional non-"CFM, SP, RPM, and Motor HP" values into the next columns to the right, skipping as needed (Name1, Value1, Name2, Value2, Name3, Value3, etc).

Anybody know what's going on?

```
'Tag Values
Do
    With Sheets("08-Attribute")
    Copy.Range("9,AttributeRowCounter").Value
    Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup((Sheets("JCX").Cells(10, AttributeRowCounter)), (Sheets("08-Attribute").Cells(1, AttributeRowCounter)), True).Value
    With Sheets("08-Attribute")
If "9,AttributeRowCounter" = "CFM" Then
    .Range("11,AttributeRowCounter").Value = Sheets("JCX").Range("14,TagNumberRow").Value
    ElseIf "9" = "SP" Then
    .Range("11,AttributeRowCounter").Value = Sheets("JCX").Range("15,TagNumberRow").Value
    ElseIf "9" = "RPM" Then
    .Range("11,AttributeRowCounter").Value = Sheets("JCX").Range("16,TagNumberRow").Value
    ElseIf "9" = "Motor_HP" Then
    .Range("11,AttributeRowCounter").Value = Sheets("JCX").Range("17,TagNumberRow").Value
    Else
    .Range("9,AttributeRowCounter").Value = Sheets("JCX").Range("20,TagNumberRow").Value
    TagValueNameColumn = TagValueNameColumn + 2
    .Range("11,AttributeRowCounter").Value = Sheets("JCX").Range("21,TagNumberRow").Value
    TagValueNameColumn = TagValueNameColumn + 2
    Loop Until Cells(1, AttributeRowCounter) = False
```

Comment: First of all, this will never return `True` - `If "9,AttributeRowCounter" = "CFM" Then`

Comment: @braX, what would it need to be then? If a value in that coordinate is CFM, then the CFM "number" needs to go in the respective cell in the JCX sheet.

Comment: You're missing an `End If`

Comment: and you have 2 `With Sheets("08-Attribute")` and no `End With`'s

Comment: @Tom I put the End If right before Loop Until, and I'm still getting the same compile error.

Comment: You're missing too `End With`'s as well?

Comment: @ThatOneGuy thanks! I put in End Withs towards the top and bottom, that resolved the current compile error. It then created another one in a different part of the code. Haha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you indent, the problems become clearer.

```
Do
    With Sheets("08-Attribute")
        copy.Range("9,AttributeRowCounter").Value
        Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup((Sheets("JCX").Cells(10, attributerowcounter)), (Sheets("08-Attribute").Cells(1, attributerowcounter)), True).Value

        With Sheets("08-Attribute")
            If "9,AttributeRowCounter" = "CFM" Then
                .Range("11,AttributeRowCounter").Value = Sheets("JCX").Range("14,TagNumberRow").Value
            ElseIf "9" = "SP" Then
                .Range("11,AttributeRowCounter").Value = Sheets("JCX").Range("15,TagNumberRow").Value
            ElseIf "9" = "RPM" Then
                .Range("11,AttributeRowCounter").Value = Sheets("JCX").Range("16,TagNumberRow").Value
            ElseIf "9" = "Motor_HP" Then
                .Range("11,AttributeRowCounter").Value = Sheets("JCX").Range("17,TagNumberRow").Value
            Else
                .Range("9,AttributeRowCounter").Value = Sheets("JCX").Range("20,TagNumberRow").Value
                TagValueNameColumn = TagValueNameColumn + 2
                .Range("11,AttributeRowCounter").Value = Sheets("JCX").Range("21,TagNumberRow").Value
                TagValueNameColumn = TagValueNameColumn + 2
            End If 'new
        End With 'new
    End With 'new
Loop Until Cells(1, attributerowcounter) = False
```

The three lines near the bottom with `'new` at the end are necessary to close the `If` block and the two `With` blocks.

Comment: You don't need the second With statement, get rid of it.